# On domains and ranges

Tags: functions

This is a really simple question that I should know how to answer at this point, but I have always been sort of confused about this notation:
$$f:A\mapsto B$$
Without specifying anything about $f$, what does the above statement mean? Like I'm sure that it means
$$\forall x\in A, f(x)\in B$$
I guess I should give an example. If $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in I\subset\Bbb R$, then obviously $f(I)\subset\Bbb R$, so would it be fair to say 
$$f:\Bbb R\mapsto\Bbb R$$
even though $f$ is not defined for all $\Bbb R$? I think you probably see what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: What about $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty), x\to \sqrt x?$

Comment: The value of $f$ should be defined for *every* $a \in A$, and $f(a)$ should be an element of $B$ for every $b \in B$. So no, it would not make sense to write $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ in that case.

Comment: @mfl what do you mean?

Comment: Can you say that the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: @T.Bongers what would be that right notation in this case

Comment: $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ would be fine, or if you know that $J$ is a set containing all possible outputs of $f$ then $f : I \to \mathbb{J}$ would work.

Comment: @T.Bongers so $g:X\mapsto\Bbb R$ would be fair iff... (what?)

Comment: If and only if $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: @T.Bongers okay. I think I get it. Could you type up an answer so we can both gain reputation?

Comment: I really don't care about gaining more reputation. If you think you understand, then write your own answer expressing that and accept it.

Comment: @T.Bongers sure haha. :)

Comment: If $f$ is a function sending real to reals then it is custom to use the notation $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ but not $f:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$ (I never encountered that). If more specifically $f$ is the function sending each $x\in\mathbb R$ to $x^2\in\mathbb R$ then it is custom to say that $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is *prescribed* (or *defined*) by $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: @drhab so there is a difference in the meanings of $\mapsto$ and $\to$

Comment: Yes. Of course I am not an authority on this, but this is the way I use $\to$ and $\mapsto$ and I never engaged the notation $f:A\mapsto B$.

Comment: @drhab were do you suggest I go to learn the differences between these notations?

Comment: Just stay here on this site :-). I think that practice and observing how others use notation is the best way to learn. It is mainly a matter of getting accustomed to it. Also you can start with developing a protocol for yourself (mine on this matter is: let $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb R$ be a function prescribed by $x\mapsto x^3$) and note when you see others doing it differently. Eventually you can adapt your protocol.